# spoj factorial (time limit exceeded error). How can i improve my solution?

Tags: c, math

Here is the link to my question on [spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL/) .

I have tried it using both recursively as well as non recursively. But I am getting time limit exceeded error. How can I improve my solution?

I have shown both the solutions below.

A) Non recursive approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int t,n,i,j=0,y;    
    unsigned long long int fact;

    scanf("%lld",&t);    
    i=t;

    while(i>0)      
    {       
        scanf("%lld",&n);        
        fact=1;

        for(y=1;y<=n;y++)            
              fact=fact*y;

        j=0;

        while(fact%10==0)          
              j++;

        printf("\n%lld",j);        
        i--;         
      }

    return 0;
}
```

B) Non recursively

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int fact(long long int);

int main() 
{      
      long long int t,n,i,j=0;      
      unsigned long long int y;

      scanf("%lld",&t);      
      i=t;

      while(i>0)       
      {

           scanf("%lld",&n);        
           y=fact(n);        
           j=0;

           while(y%10==0)          
                 j++;

           printf("\n%lld",j);

           i--;

         }

   return 0;    
}


unsigned long long int fact(long long int m) 
{  
   if(m==0)    
        return 1;

    else       
         return (m*fact(m-1));

}
```

Comment: Do not use the stream operations printf/scanf, they are very slow. Try using the functions [fread](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fread.html)/[fwrite](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fwrite.html).

Comment: @sanmukh: It sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: @md5, could you please clarify? I do not get what is bad in it; using these functions or reading everything into memory and then interpreting.

Comment: @sanmukh: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*.

Comment: Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem reduces to this **find power of 10 in n! (factorial of n), but for that we have to find power of 2 and 5 , as 10 prime factorizes into 2 and 5**

```
k1= [n/2] + [n/4] + [n/8] + [n/16] + ....
k2= [n/5] + [n/25] + [n/125] + [n/625] + ....

where as [x] is greatest integer function
k1= power of 2 in n!

k2= power of 5 in n!

ans=min(k1,k2)
```

But problem we still have is we have calculate power of 2 and 5 everytime. how to avoid that ?
 since we have to divide by power.

```
1. for 2 , sum=0
2. keep dividing n by 2 (sum+=n/2 and n=n/2)
3. and keep on adding the quotient to sum until n becomes 0.
4. finally sum will give power of 2 in n!
```

Repeat this for 5, 
and minimum among both will be the answer.

**Working Code:**

```
// Shashank Jain
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#define LL long long int
using namespace std;
LL n;
LL power(LL num)
{
        LL sum=0,m,temp;
        m=n;
        while(m>0)
        {
                temp=m/num;
                sum+=temp;
                m/=num;
        }
        return sum;
}
int main()
{
        int t;
        LL k1,k2,ans;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        while(t--)
        {
                scanf("%lld",&n);
                k1=power(2);
                k2=power(5);
                ans=min(k1,k2);
                printf("%lld\n",ans);   
        }
        return 0;
}
// Voila
```

Running Code Link :[Ideone Code Link](http://ideone.com/bAOyze)

I just submitted AC with 0.54 sec and 2.6 MB

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint - the number of zeros at the end of n! is given by the number of times that 10 cleanly divides n!.  This is equal to the minimum of the number of times 5 divides n! and the number of times 2 divides n!.  Try seeing if you can directly compute these values rather than trying to compute n!, since for even a reasonable n (say, n = 100) the value of n! is far too large to fit into a `long long` and you'll get the wrong answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: bt im using unsigned long long int  for storing N!

Comment: long int or long long int will give you the range up to 2^63-1 or about 2E9. If you make it unsigned long long int you will get al the way to 2^64-1 or 4 billion.

Comment: @Rohit- 100! is about 9.332622e+157, which is *far* bigger than the 4e9 you get in an unsigned 32-bit integer or the 1e19 you can hold in an unsigned 64 bit integer.

Comment: In fact, the biggest factorial you can represent in a 64-bit `long long` is just 20!.  Even 21! will take 66 bits.  (Factorials get really big really fast!)

Answer (score 2):

```
//count n! tail zero
//count the number of 5 in the prime factor.
int noz(int n){
    int count;

    if(n < 5) return 0;
    count = n / 5;
    return count + noz(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constraints are:

> 1 <= N <= 1000000000

But `N!` doesn't fit in a 64 bits integer (in computer memory neither). Since you can't compute the factorial itself, you have to find an other method. [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero#Factorial) gives a serious hint.

Comment: Why, it's just about 30 gigabits if my calculations are right. Peanuts!