# Number of Trailing Zeros in a Factorial in c

Tags: c, factorial

I am new to C programming
I want to find out the number of trailing zeros in a Factorial of given number

```
{
        long int n=0,facto=1,ln=0;
        int zcount=0,i=1;
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%ld",&n);
        if(n==0)
        {
          facto=1;
        }
        else
        {
           for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
           {
              facto=facto*i;
           }
        }
        printf("%ld",facto);
        while(facto>0)
        {
           ln=facto%10;
           facto/10;
           if(ln=!0)
           { 
               break;
           }
           else
           { 
               zcount+=1;
           }
        }
        printf("Tere are Total %d Trailing zeros in given factorial",zcount);
}
```

I have tried to calculate the modulo of the the number which will return the last digit of given number as the remainder and then `n/10;` will remove the last number.

After executing the program the output always shows number of trailing zeros as "0",The condition `if(ln =! 0)` always gets satisfied even if there is a zero.

Comment: the correct syntax is `if (ln != 0 )`

Comment: The expression `n=!0` assigns `!0` to `n`.

Comment: Also "  facto/10; " doesn't do much.

Comment: @user3710044 Yes, I noticed my mistake. Powers of 5 have to be handled. It's the sum of floor(n/5^i) for all i until 5^i  is larger than n.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Ending your question with “Please help me ASAP” makes it look like you think your question should have priority over the thousands of other questions asked daily here, and that may put off some of the people who could help you. This sort of empty conclusion also generally is considered bad etiquette here (even when it's not selfish), as is Randomly Capitalizing Words.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17254697/971127

Comment: In the while loop change facto/10 to facto/=10. Also change if statement to if(ln != 0) { continue;} else { zcount += 1;}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

{

```
long int n=0,facto=1,ln=0;
int zcount=0,i=1;
printf("Enter a number:");
scanf("%ld",&n);
if(n==0)
{
  facto=1;
}
else
{
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
      facto=facto*i;
   }
}
printf("%ld\n",facto);
while(facto>0)
{
   ln=(facto%10);
   facto/=10;  //here you done one mistake
   if(ln!=0)   //another one here
   {
       break;
   }
   else
   {
       zcount+=1;
   }
}
printf("Tere are Total %d Trailing zeros in given factorial",zcount);
```

}
/*Run this code it will work now and mistakes you already knows i guess*/

Answer (score 5):

Let us remember math ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero)):

```
int trailingZeroCountInFactorial(int n)
{
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 5; i <= n; i *= 5)
  {
    result += n / i;
    if(i > INT_MAX / 5) // prevent integer overflow
      break;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if(ln=!0)
```

means `ln = !0` i.e. you are assigning `!0` to `ln` so the condition is always true, change it to

```
if (ln != 0)
```

you can use an assignment as a truth value, but if you are sure you are doing it.

To prevent accidentally doing it, turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in

```
if(ln!=0) 
{ 
    // do something     
}
```

In `if ( ln=!0 )` , first `!0` is evaluated then `=` assigns `!0`(which is `1`) to `ln`, then `if` checks the value of `ln`, if the value is non-zero(in this case it is `1` due to previous assignment) then `break` statement is executed.

Also, this approach will not work for numbers larger than 25. 
It is obvious that the power of 5 in `n!` will be the answer.

The following expression gives the power of a prime `p` in `n!` :-
`f(n/p) + f(n/p^2) + f(n/p^3) + ..... (until f(n/p^k) return zero`, where `f(a)` returns the greatest integer of `a` or the floor of `a`

Answer (score 0):

```
package lb;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class l1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=s.nextInt();
    int a=n/5;
        if(a<5)
        {
        System.out.println(a);
        }
        else
        {
        int c=a/5+a;
        System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int trailingZeroCountInFactorial(int n)
{
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 5; i <= n; i *= 5)
  {
    result += n / i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

To learn, how it works, there is a great explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlYE_rDxL0U)

Answer (score 0):

*I have solved this kind of problem, I think your question is just find the number of trailing zeros of a factorial number* like - `15! = 1307674368000 if you look at the trailing 3 digits which are 000`  `Efficient code is`

```cpp
  int n;cin>>n; 
  int ans = 0;
   while(n)
   { ans += (n = n/5);}
   cout<<ans;
```

*Here one should look for int overflow, array bounds. Also, the special cases are n=1?*